# Synchronizing embedded Python in multi-threaded program

Tags: c++, python, c, multithreading

Here is the example of using Python interpreter in multi-threaded program:

```
#include <python.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void f(const char* code)
{
    static volatile auto counter = 0;
    for(; counter < 20; ++counter)
    {
        auto state = PyGILState_Ensure();
        PyRun_SimpleString(code);
        PyGILState_Release(state);

        boost::this_thread::yield();
    }
}

int main()
{
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("x = 0\n");
    auto mainstate = PyEval_SaveThread();

    auto thread1 = boost::thread(f, "print('thread #1, x =', x)\nx += 1\n");
    auto thread2 = boost::thread(f, "print('thread #2, x =', x)\nx += 1\n");
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    PyEval_RestoreThread(mainstate);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

It looks fine, but it isn't synchronized. Python interpreter releases and reacquires GIL multiple times during PyRun_SimpleString (see [docs, p.#2](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock)).

We can serialize PyRun_SimpleString call by using our own synchronization object, but it's a wrong way.

Python has its own synchronization modules - `_thread` and `threading`. But they don't work in this code:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString(R"(
import _thread
sync = _thread.allocate_lock()

x = 0
)");

auto mainstate = PyEval_SaveThread();

auto thread1 = boost::thread(f, R"(
with sync:
    print('thread #1, x =', x)
    x += 1
)");
```

- it yields an error `File "<string>", line 3, in <module> NameError: name '_[1]' is not defined` and deadlocks.

How to synchronize embedded python code most efficient way?

Comment: What output would you expect?

Comment: @Sven Marnach : thanks for your remark, updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` statement has [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue10393) in Python 3.1, but it was fixed in Python 3.2 and Python 2.7.

So the right solution is to use the `threading` module for synchronization.

To avoid such issues, one shouldn't use multi-threaded code which uses temporary variables in globals dictionary, or use different globals dictionaries for each thread.

Answer (score 4):

When CPython calls out to a function that may block (or re-enter Python), it releases the global interpreter lock before calling the function, and then re-acquires the lock after the function returns. In your code, it's your call to the built-in `print` function that causes the interpreter lock to be released and the other thread to run (see `string_print` in [stringobject.c](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release27-maint/Objects/stringobject.c)).

So you need your own lock: the global interpreter lock is not suitable for ensuring serialization of Python code that does I/O.

Since you're using the Boost thread framework, you't probably find it most convenient to use one of the Boost [thread synchronization primitives](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html), e.g. `boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex`.

[Edited: my original answer was wrong, as pointed out by Abyx.]

Comment: No, it only means that PyGILState_Ensure will block until GIL will be released. See its source code, it calls PyThread_acquire_lock.

Comment: You're right, it calls `PyEval_RestoreThread`. Let me try again.