# Embedding a Python interpreter in a multi-threaded C++ program with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, pybind11

I'm trying to use [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in order to make a 3rd party C++ library call a Python method. The library is multithreaded, and each thread creates a Python object, and then does numerous calls to the object's methods.

My problem is that the call to `py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;` deadlocks. A minimal code which reproduces the problem is given below. What am I doing wrong?

```
// main.cpp
class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper()
  {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    auto obj = py::module::import("main").attr("PythonClass")();
    _get_x = obj.attr("get_x");
    _set_x = obj.attr("set_x");
  }
  
  int get_x() 
  {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    return _get_x().cast<int>();
  }

  void set_x(int x)
  {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    _set_x(x);
  }

private:
  py::object _get_x;
  py::object _set_x;
};


void thread_func()
{
  Wrapper w;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    w.set_x(i);
    std::cout << "thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " w.get_x(): " << w.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);    
  }
}

int main() {
  py::scoped_interpreter python;
  
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    threads.push_back(std::thread(thread_func));

  for (auto& t : threads)
    t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

and the Python code:

```
// main.py
class PythonClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0

    def get_x(self):
        return self._x

    def set_x(self, x):
        self._x = x
```

Related questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153140/synchronizing-embedded-python-in-multi-threaded-program) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64429383/embed-python-c-api-in-a-multi-threading-c-program), but did not help me solve the problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue [resolved] [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410178/how-to-invoke-python-function-as-a-callback-inside-c-thread-using-pybind11). take a look if it helps; On the second thought probably it doesn't since your problem is the opposite: to run python code from C++.

Comment: What kind of application are you coding? What 3rd party library are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by releasing the GIL in the main thread, before starting the worker threads (added `py::gil_scoped_release release;`). For anybody who is interested, the following now works (also added cleaning up Python objects):

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>  
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class Wrapper
{
public:
  Wrapper()
  {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    _obj = py::module::import("main").attr("PythonClass")();
    _get_x = _obj.attr("get_x");
    _set_x = _obj.attr("set_x");

  }
  
  ~Wrapper()
  {
    _get_x.release();
    _set_x.release();
  }

  int get_x() 
  {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    return _get_x().cast<int>();
  }

  void set_x(int x)
  {
    py::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    _set_x(x);
  }

private:
  py::object _obj;
  py::object _get_x;
  py::object _set_x;
};


void thread_func(int iteration)
{
  Wrapper w;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    w.set_x(i);
    std::stringstream msg;
    msg << "iteration: " << iteration << " thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " w.get_x(): " << w.get_x() << std::endl;
    std::cout << msg.str();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);    
  }
}

int main() {
  py::scoped_interpreter python;
  py::gil_scoped_release release; // add this to release the GIL

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    threads.push_back(std::thread(thread_func, 1));

  for (auto& t : threads)
    t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to @bavaza's answer above, there is a way to self-contain both initialization and GIL release into a single class.  You have to be careful, as that class is a singleton now (no different than `scoped_interpreter`), but it's possible.  Here's the idea:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <memory>

using py = pybind11;

class PythonWrapper {
public:
    PythonWrapper() : m_interpreter() {
        // Do whatever one-time module/object initialization you want here
        py::object obj = py::module::import("main").attr("PythonClass")();  // Speeds up importing later
        
        // Last line of constructor releases the GIL
        mp_gil_release = std::make_unique<py::gil_scoped_release>();
    }
private:
    py::scoped_interpreter m_interpreter;

    // Important that this is the LAST member, so it gets destructed first, re-acquiring the GIL
    std::unique_ptr<py::gil_scoped_release> mp_gil_release;
};
```

This would replace the two objects on the stack in `main`, leaving the `Wrapper` class unchanged!  And if you wanted to have a true singleton for all your Python calls, this would help there too.

Again, thanks to @bavaza for the original solution.  It helped me get my head around the right way to use the scoped locks for my own cross-thread usage.

Answer (score -1):

[Python](https://python.org/) is known to have a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock).

So you basically need to write your own Python interpreter from scratch, or download the source code of [Python](https://python.org/) and improve it a lot.

If you are on Linux, you could consider running many Python interpreters (using appropriate [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), with [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) or [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) for [interprocess communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) - perhaps one Python process communicating with each of your C++ threads.

> What am I doing wrong?

Coding in Python something which should be coded otherwise. Did you consider trying [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/)?

Some libraries (e.g. [Tensorflow](https://tensorflow.org/)) can be called from both Python and C++. Maybe you could take inspiration from them...

In practice, if you have just a dozen C++ threads on a powerful Linux machine, you could afford having one Python [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) per C++ thread. So each C++ thread would have its own companion Python process.

Otherwise, budget several years of work to improve the source code of Python to remove its GIL. You might code your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to help you on that task -analyzing and understanding the C code of Python.

Comment: Thanks @Basile. I'm aware of the GIL and its limitations. Unfortunately, I already have a large code base in Python, and porting it is not feasible right now.

Comment: Budget months of work at least, maybe several years. If permitted, use operating system specific APIs.